# coregasm haram?

Tags: women, sex, men, human-body

My question is coregasm haram for man and women. Coregasm are Orgasmus that can Happen by doing core training. Scientists have found that this is more likely to happen to people with strong core muscles.
Men 8%
Women 10%
coregasm Can happen without feeling like having feelings for the opposite sex and without thinking about the other sex.
the men the ejaculate Happens without the penis being Stiff
(Hanafi)